# KeyError upon adding edge to networkx graph

Tags: python, python-3.5, networkx, keyerror

Hi I am currently working on ProjectEuler problem 82 and am getting a KeyError when adding edges. The strange part is that the KeyError refers to different dict_values almost every time. Here is the code...

```
import networkx as nx

with open("p082_matrix.txt") as key_file:
entries = key_file.readlines()


def split_and_cast(line_of_nums):
    nums = line_of_nums.split(",")
    return [int(x) for x in nums]


matrix_list = [split_and_cast(row) for row in entries]

for i in matrix_list:
    print(i)


class Point:
    """A two dimensional point object"""
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__dict__.values())

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__.values())


graph = nx.Graph()
for i in range(82):
    for j in range(82):
        graph.add_node(Point(i, j))

for i in range(81):
    for j in range(80):
        point = Point(i, j)
        try:
            upper_value = matrix_list[i-1][j]
            graph.add_edge(point, Point(i-1, j), weight=upper_value)
        except IndexError:
            pass
        try:

            right_value = matrix_list[i][j+1]
            graph.add_edge(point, Point(i, j+1), weight=right_value)

        except IndexError:
            pass
        try:

            lower_value = matrix_list[i+1][j]
            graph.add_edge(point, Point(i+1, j), weight=lower_value)

        except IndexError:
            pass
```

Here are a sample of the error codes...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Name/PycharmProjects/ProjectEuler/PE82.py", line 50, in    <module>
graph.add_edge(point, Point(i, j+1), weight=right_value)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-    packages\networkx-1.11-py3.5.egg\networkx\classes\graph.py", line 798, in add_edge
    datadict = self.adj[u].get(v, self.edge_attr_dict_factory())
KeyError: dict_values([60, 4])
```

A second error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Name/PycharmProjects/ProjectEuler/PE82.py", line 44, in <module>
    graph.add_edge(point, Point(i-1, j), weight=upper_value)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site- packages\networkx-1.11-py3.5.egg\networkx\classes\graph.py", line 800, in  add_edge
    self.adj[u][v] = datadict
KeyError: dict_values([14, 8])
```

Another one...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Name/PycharmProjects/ProjectEuler/PE82.py", line 50, in <module>
    graph.add_edge(point, Point(i, j+1), weight=right_value)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\networkx-1.11-py3.5.egg\networkx\classes\graph.py", line 798, in add_edge
    datadict = self.adj[u].get(v, self.edge_attr_dict_factory())
KeyError: dict_values([5, 76])
```

fyi I am from a Java background. If the answer can relate to something in Java, that would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide the error message and make sure it's clear what line of the code the error is referring to.

Comment: I think you meant for the definitions of `__eq__` and `__hash__` to be indented more.  Please edit.  I would edit it, but I don't want to take a chance of correcting it if it's the source of your error.

Comment: @Joel I have added some error messages and updated the indentations.

Comment: Not sure about the error, but something that is going to cause you problems is that (unless I'm misremembering), each time you call something like Point(i,j) it's a new object.  So your graph is going to have a lot of objects, all of which are equal to, say, Point(2,5).

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the fact you're creating multiple distinct objects whose hashes are identical.  I'm not sure of that - this is using things that are deeper than I understand in Python (and if anyone gives the answer, please call my attention to it since I'd like to understand).  For practical purposes, I think it will go away once you adapt the code so that you aren't constantly creating new objects.